# What is the difference between 12.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

A simple question that should yield a simple answer.  All I am wanting to know is what significant differences there are.

Comment: Two years appart, newer software. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes

Comment: We don't do well in the "X vs. Y" format. Our format does well if you have a concrete problem you need solved, not so much if you just want a list of things.

Comment: 14.04 ships with all the stable improvements that were made to Ubuntu since 12.04 was released and 14.04's life cycle is longer than that of 12.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the "general" desktop experience - not a lot.

It runs faster, adds new software, needs a 3D card for Unity rather than giving a choice between 2D and 3D Unity. That's about it.

14.04 isn't delivering huge changes, but it is running better than 12.04 IMO.